# .htaccess - clean urls with different parameters

Tags: .htaccess, clean-urls

Is there a way to get this to work?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?a=1&b=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?a=$1&c=$2 [L]
```

The urls should look like this:

```
http://test.com/a/b
or
http://test.com/a/c
```

It only works with the first rule.

In my case I'm trying to create a profile page and get the ID either of the session ID or via $_GET['id'].

So if I visit a profile of someone else the url is

```
index.php?page=profile&id=25
/profile/25
```

And if I'm visiting my own profile it is

```
index.php?page=profile
/profile
```

And for example I want to edit my profile it is

```
index.php?page=profile&action=edit
/profile/edit
```

I hope you understand what I mean and can help me.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between your two URLs that says one should be redirected using a=? and b=? and the other should be a=? and c=?.

Comment: For example: http://www.test.com/post/edit/ or http://www.test.com/post/25

Comment: But this just wont work, because its always trying to get to test.com/post/25

Comment: If the parameters were like: test.com/index.php?page=post&action=edit or test.com/index.php?page=post&id=25

Comment: Can you update the question with a few more examples? I think I'm beginning to understand what you are trying to do. /post/edit may need to be changed to /post/25/edit to work though (otherwise how do we know the ID?)

Comment: Yea, that was a pretty bad example. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to solving this is noticing the differences between each parameter you want to pass.

- If the visitor is looking at someone else's profile, an id (numeric) is passed.
- If the visitor is editing their profile, a parameter string (alphanumeric) is passed
- If the visitor is looking at their own profile, or another generic page, no extra parameters are passed

`.htaccess` rules can be most easily written from the most specific to the most general, so translating this, the rules become

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

It is also important to skip existing files & directories, however because RewriteCond statements only match the next RewriteRule, it is easiest to do this in a slightly different way than you are doing it.

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the file or directory exists, exit
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .? - [END]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  I'm gonna try this on monday. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Really appreciate your help!